# Swift 3 : Convert a String to an Array

Tags: swift

I am on app on SWIFT 3, I display a sentence on the screen and record the voice of the user to see if it match.

I want to extract each word of the sentence to compare each word separately.

I use the code :

```
let StringToLearn = word?.text
let StringToLearnArr = StringToLearn?.characters.split{$0 == " "}.map(String.init)
print("StringToLearn: \(StringToLearn)")
print("StringToLearnArr: \(StringToLearnArr)")


print("StringRecorded: \(StringRecorded)")
let StringRecordedArr = StringRecorded.characters.split(whereSeparator: {$0 == " "})
print("StringRecordedArr: \(StringRecordedArr)")
```

info : let StringRecorded is equal to (Siri Speech API) :

```
(result?.bestTranscription.formattedString)!
```

the console give me :

```
StringToLearn: Optional("My name is Florian")
StringToLearnArr: Optional(["My", "name", "is", "Florian"])
StringRecorded: My name is
StringRecordedArr: [Swift.String.CharacterView(_core: Swift._StringCore(_baseAddress: Optional(0x0000000174030d11), _countAndFlags: 4611686018427387906, _owner: Optional(My name is))), Swift.String.CharacterView(_core: Swift._StringCore(_baseAddress: Optional(0x0000000174030d14), _countAndFlags: 4611686018427387908, _owner: Optional(My name is))), Swift.String.CharacterView(_core: Swift._StringCore(_baseAddress: Optional(0x0000000174030d19), _countAndFlags: 4611686018427387906, _owner: Optional(My name is)))]
```

How can I have the same result for StringRecordedArr to compare each item the two arrays ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of splitting the character-view, you can use the simple `components(separatedBy:)` API.

Here's a sample that would look better and work:

```
if let toLearn = word?.text, 
   let recorded = result?.bestTranscription.formattedString  {

    let wordsToLearn = toLearn.components(separatedBy: " ")

    let recordedWords = recorded.components(separatedBy: " ")
}
```

*Note*: *nonoptionals are better than forced unwraps and optionals.*

Answer (score 2):

What you want to end up with is an array of strings, so instead of the character version use the String version: .components(separatedBy: " ") :

```
    print("StringRecorded: \(StringRecorded)")
    let StringRecordedArr = StringRecorded.components(separatedBy: " ")
    print("StringRecordedArr: \(StringRecordedArr)")
```

Comment: Thx you for that :)