# Convert string into array without quotation marks in Swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift

**My question:**

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40273195/swift-3-convert-a-string-to-an-array) explains how to convert a String containing elements separated by spaces into an array.

```
let numbers = "1 2 3 4"
let numbersArray = numbers.components(separatedBy: " ")
print(numbersArray)
// output: ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
// but I want: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

However, I'm trying to make an array *without* quotation marks, because I'm making an array of numbers, not strings.

**My attempts:**

I tried removing all quotation marks from `numbersArray`, but this didn't work as it's an array, not a string.

```
numbersArray.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "") // won't work
```

I tried something different: I tried adding each element in the array to a new array, hoping that new array wouldn't contain quotation marks. I got an error, though:

```
let numbers = "1 2 3 4" // string to be converted into array without quotes
let numbersArray = numbers.components(separatedBy: " ") // convert string into array with quotes
var newNumbersArray = [String]() // new blank array (which will be without quotes)
for i in numbersArray { // for each item in the array with quotes
  newNumbersArray += i // (hopefully) add the item in the new array without quotes
} 
print(newNumbersArray) // print the new array
```

This gives me an error:

```
Swift:: Error: cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type 'inout String'
  newNumbersArray += i
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply a [`flatMap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2903427-flatmap) call on the `[String]` array resulting from the call to `components(separatedBy:)`, applying the failable [`init(_:radix:)` of `Int`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/1540747-init) in the body of the transform closure of the `flatMap` invokation:

```
let strNumbers = "1 2 3 4"
let numbersArray = strNumbers
    .components(separatedBy: " ")
    .flatMap { Int($0) }

print(numbersArray) // [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(type(of: numbersArray)) // Array<Int>
```

Comment: Actually this answer is pretty sweet

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var newArray = [Int]()

for item in numbersArray{
    newArray.append(Int(item))
}

print(newArray)
```

Comment: This worked! I did need to add an `!` after `Int(item)` to unwrap it though

Comment: @SkeletonBow I encourage you to try this approach but appending `!` for say `let numbersArray = "1 2 a 3 4"`. As a rule of thumb, if you're not entirely familiar with optionals, your should _never_ use the forced unwrapping operator `!`.

Comment: Okay, thank you. My app does crash. I just wanted to use `!` here because it's much simpler and allows for more readable code, but I will keep your suggestion in mind and try a better approach (using if let or something)

Comment: @SkeletonBow or possible the safe and quite readable `flatMap` approach shown in my answer below (which also allows you to let the `newArray` be immutable).

Comment: I'm still a beginner, so I didn't quite understand your answer. I'll make a note to look at yours when I'm more experienced, though. In that way I'll actually be able to understand what I'm doing better :)

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3.0**

Try this.. Chaining method makes it easy.

```
let temp = "1 2 3 4 5 6"
var numbers: [Int] = []

temp.components(separatedBy: " ").forEach { numbers.append(Int($0)!) }
```

print(numbers) //[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

Comment: I would have selected this as the answer, but the current accepted answer is basically what I was trying to do, but corrected. This is also a very good answer, though.